# Django How to calculate monthly interest over an objects value?

Tags: python, mysql, django, oop, instance

I search for an answer to my problem and only got this:

> This isn't really a Django problem, and your questions is a little
>   unclear. You basically need to apply the compound interest formula in
>   python to an instance of this model:
>
> ```
> account = Account.objects.get(pk=<something>)
> calc_interest = lambda value: value * account.rate
> amount = account.principal
> for i in xrange(12):
>     interest = calc_interest(amount)
>     amount += interest
>     print 'month {}: {} ({} interest)'.format(i, amount, interest)
> ```
>
> This will give you:
>
> month 0: 1050.0 (50.0 interest) month 1: 1102.5 (52.5 interest) month
>   2: 1157.625 (55.125 interest) month 3: 1215.50625 (57.88125 interest)
>   month 4: 1276.2815625 (60.7753125 interest) month 5: 1340.09564062
>   (63.814078125 interest) month 6: 1407.10042266 (67.0047820312
>   interest) month 7: 1477.45544379 (70.3550211328 interest) month 8:
>   1551.32821598 (73.8727721895 interest) month 9: 1628.89462678 (77.5664107989 interest) month 10: 1710.33935812 (81.4447313389
>   interest) month 11: 1795.85632602 (85.5169679058 interest)

If that's correct, where to I put this formula? In which Django file?

Answer (score 1):

This can be a public method of your `Account` model. Maybe something like this:

```
class Account(models.Model):

    #..other methods and properties here

    def montly_interest(self):
        amount = self.principal
        calc_interest = lambda value: value * self.rate
        montly = []
        for i in xrange(12):
            interest = calc_interest(amount)
            amount += interest
            montly.append((i, amount, interest))
        return montly
```